# We're in an abyss of inactivity... a massive one

Tags: discussion

We are in extreme inactivity. Reviews rarely pop up and we aren't doing anything really, anxious to get something done on this site.

Sure, (all of the following stats are from [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61013/coffee)), we're good on daily views and almost there with the avid users stats. But our question rate has fallen to a question every two days. I was shocked to see that, the 50th latest question was asked in *March*. That's over 3 months ago, over 90 days ago. Our reputation leagues show it as well, our number one user this week got... 115 rep. Also, this is our first meta post since November 2017. Our chatroom? All I see are intervals of days and even *weeks*.

So, what can we do to get more people into this site other than more ads?

Comment: For many people, it's hot out there right now, perhaps their thoughts turn to other drinks.

Comment: [We're doing ok](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites).

Comment: @fredley technically, yes (phew...). But overall low actvity is also a bit frustrating for the users. And I’m not even talking about the Percolator, which instead of bubbling happily gets a desperate “blubb” every few weeks.

Comment: I think that while we're not going to be shut down there's no reason not to consider ways of growing the community. More people means more knowledge, but I think we also have to contend with the fact that coffee is a narrow knowledge set compared to, say, cooking in general or programming. As such there will be fewer questions to ask and fewer to answer.